Netlify: Link to home directory works, whereas link to subroute doesn’t
I have uploaded a VueJS app on Netlify and deployed it there successfully.
The following link works all right:
https://florianloveslanguages.netlify.app/
But if I send this link
https://florianloveslanguages.netlify.app/fr/french/breveshistoires/renardreligeux
to a friend, the link doesn’t work.
However, if you go first to the homepage https://florianloveslanguages.netlify.app/
and then click on the menu for “Français” and then on “Un renard religeux”, the link to the above subroute works.
How can I fix this, so that the link with the subroute works directly?

It's an issue with Netlify's web server trying to serve an index page at the requested URL path, which is how multi-page apps (MPA) work.  Being a single page app, you need Netlify to always serve the project's root index file where vue-router will then handle the proper in-app navigation.  See the official documentation and maybe also this netlify blog

@yoduh So does that mean that it is impossible to send a link with a subroutine to a friend so that he/she can directly open the link? I just don't want to read a lot of documentation to get an explanation of why it's not possible

It is very possible, it just needs to be configured to work that way.  I believe the very basic method is to create a file called _redirects (no file extension) in the project's public folder, and the only content should be /*   /index.html   200

@yoduh Thanks so much! That just worked! Why don't you make an answer out of your comment? Or should I answer my own question?
